# Is statement in for each loop executed each iteration?

Tags: c++, c++11, foreach, containers, ranged-loops

I have a function which returns a container. Let's just call it '`Container`'.

```
Container GenerateRandomContainer() { ... }
```

This function will generate a container with random elements that are different each call.

When I iterate through this container using a for each loop like this:

```
for(Element e : GenerateRandomContainer()) { ... }
```

Will it generate a new `Container` each iteration or will it generate only one when the for each loop is entered?

Comment: `GenerateRandomContainer()` will only be called once. See also  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for , it explains exactly how range-for construct is executed.

Comment: I'll have a look at it.

Comment: Note that this copies each element to `e`;  use `Element &e` (or `auto& e`) to refer to each element in the container

Comment: That's a good hint, thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [range-based for loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) is equivalent as follows:

```
{
    auto && __range = range_expression ; 
    auto __begin = begin_expr ;
    auto __end = end_expr ;
    for ( ; __begin != __end; ++__begin) { 
        range_declaration = *__begin; 
        loop_statement 
    } 
}
```

Note the 1st statement `auto && __range = range_expression ;` (`range_expression` will be `GenerateRandomContainer()` for your code); that means the `Container` will be generated only once, and iterates on all the elements of it.

Answer (score 0):

It will generate a container only once and then the loop will iterate through the elements generated.